# How to get image data from Django form which returns False for is_valid()

Tags: django, django-forms

How to save image in Django form that is not validated. I could able to save data of Charfield using

```
title = form_name["title"].data
```

Other data that are passed are getting saved but image is not getting saved. How to fix it.

```
form = forms.FormName()
if request.method == "POST":
    form_name = FormName(data = request.POST)
    title = form_name["title"].data
    thumbnail = form_name["thumbnail"].data
    content = form_name["content"].data
    tags = form_name["tags"].data
    instance = htmlpage(title=title, thumbnail=thumbnail, content= content, tags=tags, by=request.user)
    instance.save()
```

Comment: You need `request.FILES` in the form. But why are you accepting data that has not been validated? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: @DavidAlford Alford The data returned by summernote form is not being validated. Can you post the above code updated with this